# Why are collision checks in Unity2D providing various outcomes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to recreate AA in Unity2D to kind of learn how everything works, I'm using a YouTube tutorial to guide me through it and I have the exact code in the video but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, the pins won't stop at the same time when they touch the rotating ball (seen below). Some will go halfway into the ball while others will stop prematurely.

[image: Pin heights differing]

Here's the pin code (Pin.cs):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pin : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool moving = true;

    public float speed = 20f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Update() {
        if (moving)
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
        if (collider.tag == "Rotator") {
            moving = false;
            transform.SetParent(collider.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your rigidbodies set to Continuous or Discrete?

Comment: @Draco18s [see here](https://ibb.co/chhuKU) I have it set to Discrete and the body type to Kinematic

Comment: Change it to Continuous.

Comment: @Draco18s it didnt work, [img](https://ibb.co/hG31zU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `FixedUpdate()` instead `Update()`.

Refer to [Unity Documentation - FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) link, `FixedUpdate()` should be used instead of `Update()` when dealing with Rigidbody.

So, Change your code to this:

```
public class Pin : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        if (moving)
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: It should be “*Time.fixedDeltaTime” if you want it to be fps indepentend movement. It’s really bad to use Time.deltaTime as a factor in FixedUpdate